# Customize user permissions [SharePoint 2010]

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I am customizing the user permission levels in SharePoint 2010.
I would like to create a group of people that could upload, edit or delete documents but not create/amend new site pages.

I unchecked the "Add and Customize Pages  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor." for that group of people, however, they can still create a new site page.

Please advice how I can set up this permission. Any helps is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Your group and permissions are fine. Just on the pages document library stop inheriting permissions from its parent and give read only access to all groups except for Designers and Site Administrators.